# Im trying to make a whitelist checker with python

Tags: python

Im new to python and I have an excel sheet with names in the first column and I want to make a python code where a user will input a name and the script will check if the name is in the column. I am able to print out the rows in the column but I am not sure how to check it one by one in a loop.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('Desktop\python\excel.xlsx')
sheet = book['Sheet1']

for row in sheet.rows:
    whitelist = row[0].value
    print (whitelist)

user_input = input(message)

if user_input == whitelist:
    print("User is whitelisted")
else:
    print("The user is not whitelisted")
```

Comment: put the condition inside the for loop, and the user input before that loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not storing the names anywhere.  Put them in a set, then checking is easy.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('Desktop\python\excel.xlsx')
sheet = book['Sheet1']

whitelist = set(row[0].value for row in sheet.rows)

user_input = input(message)

if user_input in whitelist:
    print("User is whitelisted")
else:
    print("The user is not whitelisted")
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you for your help!

Comment: If it worked for you, well you can accept the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

that a easy, just write `if` inside `for` like this

```
# Ask the user to input  the name
user_input = input("Enter name: ")

for row in sheet.rows:
    # now check that one by one 
    if user_input == row[0].value:
       print("User is whitelisted")
```